# Can I get price feed information directly from ChainLink oracles rather than from the aggregated contract?

Tags: blockchain, chainlink, data-feeds

I've been experimenting with ChainLink recently and am fascinated of what it can do. I already used the code provided here [ChainLink Docs](https://docs.chain.link/docs/get-the-latest-price/) in Python and got it to work. However, I've been searching all day to find a way to access the individual oracle prices rather than the aggregated one. I know i.e. that for BNB / USD there are 9 nodes which i found out here: [ChainLink Market](https://market.link/feeds/e72c66f2-3ff0-45e1-940b-09b958f8ac59/nodes?network=56)

I tried the API calls for the oracle contracts, result: empty responses.
Also, I've found a lot of documentation on how to do it out of a smart contract, but i have almost zero experience with solidity / smart contracts.

So: Is there a way to call the price feeds from individual oracles without using smart contracts?

Answer (score 1):

The main purpose of oracles is to allow smart contracts to communicate to the outside world, hence why you see most examples focusing on this. From where exactly are you trying to access this data from? eg from a webUI or something?

To answer your question, you can't access individual oracle node responses with Chainlink. Getting data from an individual node or data source isn't recommended due to it being prone to manipulation or a [price oracle attack](https://blog.chain.link/flash-loans-and-the-importance-of-tamper-proof-oracles/). This is why Chainlink aggregates responses, taking things into account such as volume, liquidity etc to come to a final aggregated response that contains sufficient market coverage, and this is the value that you should use.

If you just want to access a particular price from a particular website, regardless of the warnings described above, then you can use Chainlink [Any-API](https://docs.chain.link/docs/request-and-receive-data/) functionality

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I'm trying to access it from my Python program. The price oracle attack article was interesting as it is part of my research. I'm not using the data for anything critical so I don't care about the risk. Will try using Any-API now.

Answer (score 0):

While requesting data from a single Chainlink oracle introduces non-decentralization risks (ie, do you trust this oracle team with your data?), there are several reputable community oracles out there who are willing to take on this task (disclaimer: I work for one of these teams).

While market.link has since been deprecated, a good way to find a willing oracle is join the Chainlink Official [Discord server](https://discord.com/invite/chainlink), and post the details of your request to the **#operator-requests** channel.

You can also feel free to check our website for a list of publicly-available Chainlink jobs and addresses that we provide.